# How do I change the color of the Kendo Grid toolbar "Download to Excel" button?

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-grid

I'd like to customize the color of the "Export To Excel" button which the Kendo grid UI provides in the toolbar:

[image: screenshot of Kendo Grid toolbar with button]

I've been able to change the color of the toolbar *itself* using this definition in Site.css:

```
.k-grid-toolbar {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: none;
}
```

...but adding similar style definitions for .k-grid-toolbar-button, .k-grid-button or .k-grid-toolbar-item doesn't change the button color.

I also tried expanding the toolbar statement:

```
$('#search_grid').kendoGrid({
    toolbar: [
        {
            name: 'excel',
            text: 'Download to Excel' 
        }
    ],
```

... and specifying "attributes", "class" or "style" in this definition. I can change the button *text*, but not the color. How can I change the button color?

Many thanks to you all. I've learned so much from this site but this is my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your css:

```
.k-grid .k-header .k-button {
    background-color: red;
}
```